# Buscando valor en un xpath - groovy

Tags: xpath, groovy

Muy buenas, actualmente tengo el siguiente fichero xml (person.xml)

Jane
      Smith
      31
  
 
    Juan
    Smith
    31


En le proceso que estoy haciendo, se cual va a ser el valor de var y lo que necesito obtener es el valor de "firstName"

La primera query que estaba preparando era:

```
def person = new XmlParser().parse(new File("/tmp/person.xml"))
println "first name: ${people.person[0].firstName.text()}"
```

Lo curioso que people no lo reconoce groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:

Si tanto en el xml quito la tag people, la query anterior funciona.

Si intento lanzar la query

```
println "first name: ${person.@var=='hola'.firstName.text()}"
```

Me aparece el mismo error anterior groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:

¿Como debería lanzar la query para que dado el valor de "var" pueda obtener el valor de firstName?

un saludo Javi

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas,
esto fue lo que hice y está operativo:

```
import groovy.util.XmlParser
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult

def String xml = """<people>
                        <person var="1">
                            <firstName>Jane</firstName>
                            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
                            <age>31</age>
                        </person>
                        <person var="2">
                            <firstName>Juan</firstName>
                            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
                            <age>32</age>
                        </person>
                    </people>
                  """
def GPathResult people = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def GPathResult person = people.children().find { GPathResult node ->
    node.name() == 'person' && node.getProperty("@var") == '2'
}

def GPathResult firstName = person.children().find { GPathResult node ->
    node.name() == 'firstName'
}
firstName.text()
```